# OBIEE Impact analysis (using SQL or PL/SQL)

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, obiee, impact-analysis

I have been using Oracle Catalog Manager to determine which reports are being affected by RPD columns. I'm wondering if there is any ORACLE table where all these data is kept.

For example, by using SQL, am I able to get these data:

1. How are the report columns defined back in metadata?
2. What are the OBIEE objects (Analysis, BIP Reports, Prompts and filters etc.) that are being referenced by a column(s)?
3. How are columns mapped through metadata?
4. Who are the owners of reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presentation Catalog objects are not stored in a database. They are XML files on the file system in the folder structure holding your catalog!

What you want to get you get through Catalog Manager the fat client tool or through the command line runcat.sh/cmd which is basically Catalog Manager wihtout a GUI